# Can I use PHP try/catch around a large block of HTML?

Tags: php, exception, try-catch

I would like to surround this entire block of code in a try/catch since its causing an error when there is nothing in the grid array. Whats the best way to do this?

```
 <?php foreach ($grid->result() as $idx => $row): ?>  <?php if ($idx % 3 == 2): ?>
   <div class="img_grid_3"><img src="/images/thumb/<?= $row->images_name; ?>" /></div>
    <?php else: ?>
   <div class="img_grid"><img src="/images/thumb/<?= $row->images_name; ?>" /></div>
   <?php endif; ?>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe Im missing the point but why dont you test $grid before doing the foreach?

```
<?php if($grid): ?>
  .... foreach ....
<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: Im using the codeigniter framework. Grid will always be an array but it may not be populated.

Answer (score 0):

If I got you right, you're looking for the `@` error suppression operator. If you pass an empty array to foreach, you'll get a PHP warning, you can't catch this with a `try/catch` block.

```
<?php @foreach ($grid->result() as $idx => $row): ?>
   <?php if ($idx % 3 == 2): ?>
   <div class="img_grid_3"><img src="/images/thumb/<?= $row->images_name; ?>" /></div>
   <?php else: ?>
   <div class="img_grid"><img src="/images/thumb/<?= $row->images_name; ?>" /></div>
   <?php endif; ?>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

It's possible to use a try catch block with html contents too, but it will obviously only catch [`Exceptions`](http://ch2.php.net/exceptions).

Note that it's cleaner to check wheter the array is empty or not before you use it in a `foreach` block.

Answer (score 0):

`foreach` will not produce an error if the array is empty.

So either `$grid` is not an object, or `result()` is returning a non-array like `false` or `null`. If the former, surround the `foreach` with `if ($grid)`, of the latter, than use `if (!empty($grid->result()))`